# Heroku - Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, yarnpkg

been using the http://jumbo-react.g-axon.com/ framework for a client. This framework is based on react and uses webpack to build. It works on my local machine, but when uploading to Heroku I get this error:

```
react-material@2.0.0 start /app
2018-08-24T10:05:46.551774+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server --hot --open
2018-08-24T10:05:46.551775+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-24T10:05:47.905809+00:00 app[web.1]: Project is running at http://localhost:24282/
2018-08-24T10:05:47.906248+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack output is served from /assets/
2018-08-24T10:05:47.906347+00:00 app[web.1]: Content not from webpack is served from ./public/, ./src/
2018-08-24T10:05:47.906399+00:00 app[web.1]: 404s will fallback to /index.html
2018-08-24T10:05:47.939064+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to open browser. If you are running in a headless environment, please do not use the open flag.
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917006+00:00 app[web.1]: Hash: 7feed7b626257881787d
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917049+00:00 app[web.1]: Version: webpack 3.12.0
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917052+00:00 app[web.1]: Time: 49556ms
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917058+00:00 app[web.1]: Asset     Size  Chunks                    
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917128+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

*Cut the middle to make it easier to read*

```
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917146+00:00 app[web.1]: [../node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1.04 kB {30} [built]
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917124+00:00 app[web.1]: [../node_modules/react-hot-loader/patch.js] ./node_modules/react-hot-loader/patch.js 40 bytes {30} [built]
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917147+00:00 app[web.1]: [../node_modules/webpack/hot/only-dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/only-dev-server.js 2.37 kB {30} [built]
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917143+00:00 app[web.1]: [../node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {30} [built]
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917151+00:00 app[web.1]: + 1784 hidden modules
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917126+00:00 app[web.1]: [../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:24282] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:24282 7.93 kB {30} [built]
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917152+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack: Compiled successfully.
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917142+00:00 app[web.1]: [../node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 kB {30} [built]
2018-08-24T10:06:37.917150+00:00 app[web.1]: [./index.js] ./src/index.js 848 bytes {30} [built]
2018-08-24T10:06:44.847917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-08-24T10:06:44.847917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-08-24T10:06:44.963250+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-08-24T10:06:44.977771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

When initially searching for an answer, the most common response was:  because I was hard setting the port instead of using `process.env.PORT`, but I've now changed that in the webpack settings:

```
 return {
        context: this.srcPathAbsolute,
        devtool: 'eval',
        devServer: {
            contentBase: ['./public/', './src/'],
            publicPath: '/assets/',
            historyApiFallback: true,
            hot: true,
            inline: true,
            port: process.env.PORT || 3000
```

But Heroku still shows this crash report. Every time it does show, however, the app is now using a different port- meaning it's now being set by Heroku.

The build time of webpack is 50s and I was wondering if that was the problem. Is it building too slow and then afterwards not having enough time to bind to a port before the 60s Heroku limit is up?

Honestly not really sure where to go from here, before hacking through files and changing the structure of the app for efficiency (although not a bad thing to do) I wanted to know if I was on the right trail. Would hate to change things in the app and accidentally create more problems when not solving the initial problem that was the most pressing.

If you have any suggestions, really would like to hear.

Thanks for your time.

```
Node: v8.11.3
Yarn: 1.6.0
Webpack: ^3.5.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run heroku in a `development` environment. You'll want to make sure that your environment is set to `production` and that you get web pack to compile all your assets.

The first line of the heroku output says `webpack-dev-server --hot --open` which suggests you're trying to use the web packer dev server in production which, as the name suggests, probably won't work.

This might help? https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-react-redux-to-heroku/